# 500 internal server error because of .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

So i got that error and the problem is in the .htaccess file. 
Here is the code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

<IfDefine APACHE2>
    AcceptPathInfo On
</IfDefine>

<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # RewriteRule (.layout1\.htm) templates$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

So can anyone suggest a solution for that problem? Thank you!

Comment: check error log file, for linux it is under `/var/log/httpd` or `/var/log/apache2`

Answer (score 2):

Please check error log go to the directory  cd /var/log/apache2
type ls -->enter.
if you have an error .htaccess: Invalid comman$

than  have solved this issue by running a command.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
```